# dataflow Error received from SDK harness for instruction

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a GCS bucket where i receive files every minute,So i am using pub/sub method to get new files and doing some transformation and storing into another bucket.but i am getting

> "Error received from SDK harness for instruction"

This is my Code :

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
import logging
import argparse
from google.cloud import language
from google.cloud.language import enums
from google.cloud.language import types
from datetime import datetime
import apache_beam as beam 
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import StandardOptions
from apache_beam.io.textio import ReadFromText, WriteToText

def run(argv=None):
    """Build and run the pipeline."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--output_filename', required=True,
        help=('Output GCS bucket '
            '"gs:/***********/output_files".'))
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    group.add_argument(
        '--input_topic',
        help=('Input PubSub topic of the form '
            '"projects/*******/topics/testsub1".'))
    group.add_argument(
        '--input_subscription',
        help=('Input PubSub subscription of the form '
            '"projects/*********/*****/test_subscription."'))
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

  # We use the save_main_session option because one or more DoFn's in this
  # workflow rely on global context (e.g., a module imported at module level).
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = 'DataflowRunner'
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
    pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)


    # Read from PubSub into a PCollection.
    if known_args.input_subscription:
        messages = (p
                    | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(
                        subscription=known_args.input_subscription)
                    .with_output_types(bytes))
    else:
        messages = (p
                    | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=known_args.input_topic)
                    .with_output_types(bytes))

    lines = messages | 'decode' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))

    class Split(beam.DoFn):
        def process(self,element):
            element = element.rstrip("\n").encode('utf-8')
            text = element.split(',') 
            result = []
            for i in range(len(text)):
                dat = text[i]
                #print(dat)
                client = language.LanguageServiceClient()
                document = types.Document(content=dat,type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT)
                sent_analysis = client.analyze_sentiment(document=document)
                sentiment = sent_analysis.document_sentiment
                data = [
                (dat,sentiment.score)
                ] 
                result.append(data)
            return result

    class WriteToCSV(beam.DoFn):
        def process(self, element):
            return [
                "{},{}".format(
                    element[0][0],
                    element[0][1]
                )
            ]

    Transform = (lines
                | 'split' >> beam.ParDo(Split())
                | beam.ParDo(WriteToCSV()) 
                | beam.io.WriteToText(known_args.output_filename)
    )
    result = p.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
  run()
```

I am running this by writing the following code :

> python SentAnal.py \ --runner DataflowRunner \ --project
>   b********** \ --temp_location gs://baker********/tmp/ \
>   --input_topic "projects/******/topics/*****" \ --output_filename "gs://*********/********" \ --streaming \ --experiments=allow_non_updatable_job

Comment: Can you share your stack trace? I believe the problem may be the WritetoText transform does not support streaming.

Comment: I am getting the same error!!! It is functional running it using the default Runner, but whenever I put it in GCP...

Comment: @jStaff i think the issue was because from the pubsub i wasn't getting the content of the file rather i was getting the metadata .there must be some error in your program kindly check